# Integral over triangle

Tags: integration

Let's consider $\mathbb{T}$, a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $a,b,c$. I'd be interested to know how to compute the following integral (Lebesgue measure)
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\mathbb{T}|} \int_{\mathbb{T}} x dx. 
\end{equation}

Since the vertices are arbitrary I thought about doing a coordinate transformation such that the vertices of the triangle $\Delta$ are given as the points $(0,0), (1,0),(0,1)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
x(u,v)=a_1+u(b_1-a_1)+v(c_1-a_1)  ~~ \text{and} ~~
y(u,v)=a_2+u(b_2-a_2)+v(c_2-a_2)
\end{equation}.

With this coordinate transformation we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{T}} f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{\Delta} f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) |J(u,v)| d(u,v)
\end{equation}
where $J(u,v)$ stands for the Jacobian, the determinant of which is given as
\begin{equation}
J(u,v)=(b_1-a_1)(c_2-a_2)-(c_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2).
\end{equation}

I don't really know how to proceed since I'm not sure what my $f$ actually is. Can I even do it with this coordinate transformation?

In the second step I'd like to show that for $p(x)$, a polynomial of degree at most 1, the following equality holds:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{T}}p(x) dx = \frac{|\mathbb{T}|}{3} \sum_{k=1}^3 p(x_i)
\end{equation}
Here I have the same problem as before: I'm not sure how to compute the integral on the left side.

Comment: From where you get $f$? It is not in first integral.

Comment: Yes, this is just the general integral transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) but I'm not sure how to apply it correctly

Comment: Integral transformation is clear, but you also need $f$ to be in the first integral. Otherwise, what do you understand by $xdx$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: This is exactly what I was confused of.  What is my $f$ if my integral is $x dx$?

Comment: From where you take task? What is context? If we are speaking about center of gravity and it is same with center of mass, then you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass

Comment: Yes, it's the center of mass the the result is supposed to be $(a+b+c)/3$ but I don't understand how to derive it.

Comment: Take look at Kleppner D., Kolenkow R. - An Introduction to Mechanics-CUP (2013), page 123.

Answer (score 2):

This integral  is the center of gravity of the triangle and the result is $\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c).$

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how to derive this result, i.e how to compute the integral step by step?

Comment: Start with the triangle $00,10,01.$ The area is $1/2$ (OK?). The first coordinate of the gravity center $ I_0$ is $2\int_0^1(\int_0^y xdx)dy= 1/3$ The second is also $1/3$ therefore the result $ (a+b+c)/3$ is proved for this particular triangle $T_0$. Now for the general case $T$ make an affine transformation $f(v)=Av+B$ such that $f(00)=a,\ f(10)=b,\ f(01)=c.$ In the integral $I=\frac{1}{|T|}\int_T wdw$ we make the change of variable $w=f(v)$ obtaining $I=\frac{1}{|T|}\int_{T _0}f(v)|f'(v)|dv$ while $|T|=\int_T dw=\int_{T _0}|f'(v)|dv=\int_{T _0}|\det A|dv.$ Therefore $I=f(I_0)$

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why the frist coordinate is given by this integral?